# Including files from library on publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have created a WPF application which uses a library in the same solution. To make things easier, let's call them MyClient and MyLibrary.

In MyLibrary I import some `.dll` files using `DLLImport()`.
I included these files in the MyLibrary project, they are set as `Content` and `Copy if newer`.
When MyLibrary is built, the files are copied into the `/bin/Release/` or `/bin/Debug/` directories.

MyClient references MyLibrary, but upon publishing, the `.dll` files are missing, so the application doesn't work properly.

As a workaround, I have included the `.dll` files in the MyClient project and that seems to work, but it defeats the point of a library.

I'm hoping someone knows a way to do this in a way which lets me keep the files only in the MyLibrary project.

Comment: I am not sure on this so a comment not an answer....IF you right click on your project and select unload and then right click and click edit.  Look in the <ItemGrouo> for the <Content Include=".... tags.  Maybe you could include your files by appending entries in there.
I use it to exclude certain files like my SQL Scripts but it would seem logical that you could include  other files also.  Hope this helps.

Comment: So I already have `<Content Include="MyLibraryNeedsThisFile.dll">` in the MyLibrary project. And that gets included on the MyLibrary build, but it does not get included for the MyClient publish. To do that, I'd have to add `<Content Include="MyLibraryNeedsThisFile.dll">` to MyClient's project file as well. But that does mean that I have to keep the files in two places which is not ideal. It does work, but I'm looking for a solution where it works "properly" if that makes sense. I need the files to be included from the library only.